# Which one is more correct to use: "Will you turn on the lights in the kitchen?" OR "Will you turn the lights on in the kitchen?"

Tags: grammar

I'm basically asking if it's "turn on the lights" vs "turn the lights on."

Answer (score 3):

"turn on" is a particle verb, and the "on" particle can be moved after a following object.  Here,
all of the following are grammatical:

> He turned on the lights in the kitchen.
>    He turned the lights on in the kitchen.
>    He turned the lights in the kitchen on.

The last of the above is okay because "in the kitchen" can be part of the object "the lights in the kitchen" if it is interpreted as a modifier of "the lights".

"on the lights" looks a little like a prepositional phrase, but it isn't one, as you can see if you try moving it around as if it were a prepositional phrase:

> *On which things did he turn in the kitchen?

When the object is a pronoun, moving the particle after it is obligatory:

> *He turned on them in the kitchen.
>    He turned them on in the kitchen.

Answer (score -1):

Both of your sentences are correct.
For more help visit.
 http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/turn-off-the-light-or-turn-the-light-off.906215/

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct.  The first is a hair more idiomatic, but it really depends on the context.

"Turn on the lights in the kitchen" might be said when you enter your house and it's completely dark.

"Turn the lights on in the kitchen" might be said when the lights are already on several places but you have need to specifically have the lights in the kitchen turned on.

But it's not something to get anxious about.

Answer (score -3):

My technical suspicion is that "turn on" is a compound term that "should" be kept together, all things equal. But similar to avoiding split infinitives, all things are never equal. In fact to avoid the ambiguity of whether "you" or "the lights" are modified by "in the kitchen", I would even say "Will you turn the lights in the kitchen on?” is also just as, if not more, correct.

Comment: -1. I don't think "in the kitchen" modifies "you" in the way it would if we were to say "Hey, you in the kitchen, turn on the lights!"

Comment: No, but a person away from the kitchen but for some reason near a switch for the kitchen lights could certainly respond to "Will you turn the lights on in the kitchen?" with "Is from here all right, or did you mean *I* should also be in the kitchen?" without being presumed pedantic. It *is* ambiguous.

Comment: OK. ...using the switch in the kitchen. Add that to your answer and SE will let me remove my -1 :)